# Variables returning wrong int values

Tags: java, oop, variables, joptionpane, netbeans-8

Coded the following lines with the intent of inserting 2 values into a Dialog Box and have assigned to 2 different variables. Let's say I insert 22, it then should display as 2x2 = 4 in the textField, instead, it prints something like 50 x 50 = 2500.

```
String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual cálculo deseja fazer? (AB = A x B)", "AB");

   aNum = a.charAt(0);
   bNum = a.charAt(1);
   int cNum = aNum*bNum;

    Game.getNumbers(aNum, bNum);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(aNum, bNum);

    TF1.setText(Game.First() +" x "+ Game.Second() +" = "+ cNum);
```

Classes involved:

```
public class Game1 {

private int first = 0;
private int second = 0;
private int score = 0;
private int hiScore = 0;


public void numTotalCheck(int a){

    String option1 = null;
    char option = 0;

    do{
    if (a == (first*second)){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parabéns. Você acertou!");

        score = score + 100;
        if(score > hiScore){

            hiScore = score;
        }
    }else{

        score = score - 100;
        if(score > hiScore){

            hiScore = score;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Errado!");

        option1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja jogar novamente? <S/N>");
        option = option1.charAt(0);
    }
    }while((option == 's') || (option == 'S'));


}

public void getNumbers(int a, int b){

    first = a;
    second = b;
}

public int First(){

    return first;
}

public int Second(){

    return second;
}
```

Results:

[Result of "22" input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YEY5.png)

Comment: You might want to look at an ascii table.  `'2'` is `50` when used as an `int`.

Comment: I... Did not know that. Being an IT student, I think it's something I should. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, IMO you should know the following ASCII values (I'm a computer science and applied maths student): 13 = linefeed ('\n'), 32 = space (' '), 48 = '0' (and 49 = '1', 50 = '2'...), 65 = 'A' and 97 = 'a'. These are good to know. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `charAt(index)` returns a char, which you then implicitely parse into an int. The int value of '2' is 50, so it's 50 * 50 = 2500.

An easy fix would be to ask for an input format like A;B. Then you could do the following:

```
String s =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two numbers like this: Number A;Number B", "AB");
String[] temp = s.split(";");
if(temp.length == 2) {
  try {
    int aNum = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
    int bNum = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
    int cNum = aNum*bNum;
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // One or both of the values weren't ints.
  }
} else {
  // Some error here, because of too few/ too many values
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The code is working as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating a character (`char`) like a number (`integer`). Here's an example to isolate what you're seeing.

This code takes a String value of "2" and gets a character out of it, then prints the character.

```
char c = "2".charAt(0);
System.out.println("c: " + c);

--> c: 2
```

If you try the same thing, but store the result as an `int`, the value that is stored is not same thing, but instead is "50":

```
int i = "2".charAt(0);
System.out.println("i: " + i);

--> i: 50
```

Under the covers, any character value is represented numerically, so character '2' is integer 50. You can dig up an ASCII chart to see how these are mapped.

There are lots of ways to fix your code, but since you already start with a string value, one way you could get the right result is to use `Integer.parseInt()`, like this:

```
int parsedValue = Integer.parseInt("2");
System.out.println("parsedValue: " + parsedValue);

--> parsedValue: 2
```